# How to add new vs returning report in new widget google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I want to show the New vs returning report, under behavior menu on google analytic site accounts, on my site admin dashboard.
I hope there is a option google analytic to set new widget and add this report over there. And that way I can show this report with just selecting this new widget.
But I am no able to add this report after adding new widget.
someone can help please to guide me how can I add this "New vs Returning " report to my new created widget.
Or is there any API to retrieve this report to my site?

Answer (score 0):

You cant add new reports to the main menu on Google Analytics website.

The only way to add and see custom reports is, in the Dashboards or though  customization -> Custom Reports.